# Download file from API and save/upload it to Google Storage using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to download file from API and save/upload it to Google Storage.
Can anyone help what I’m doing wrong?

```
from google.cloud import storage
import urllib

#create storage client
storage_client = storage.Client()

#Get file:
url = 'https://....'
filename = 'test.xlsx'

bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('my-data-test-bucket')

#Upload:
filedata = urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename)
datafile = bucket.blob(filename)
datafile.upload_from_filename(filedata)
```

Error message: **TypeError: expected string or buffer**

If I try to save it as string like this:
**datafile.upload_from_string(filedata)**

I got error: **TypeError: ('test.xlsx', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x7f9fc927a6c8>) could not be converted to bytes**

I don't have much experience with Python so this mighty be stupid question. I was keep hitting head to wall to solve this and I appreciate all help :)

Answer (score 0):

in `datafile.upload_from_filename(filedata)`
can you try replace `filedata` with `filename` or path of needed file